# Band lock in wifi

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-wifi

Can I lock a wifi band[2.4 and 5GHz] in android from my application? I found that it was possible in earlier android versions and it has now been removed.

Please help with the android version with which it was supported.

Comment: Please answer i am stuck because of it

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?